# Unable to run a function inside another function: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined / Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I want to run a callback test() from the onClose() function. I tried to find the solution across StackOverflow but I was unable to solve the problem. Running this code gives me undefined errors mentioned in the comments with codeblocks

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isPaid: false
    }
    this.test = this.test.bind(this)
  }
  test = () =>{
    const { isPaid } = this.state
    console.log(isPaid)
    this.setState({isPaid: true})
  }

  render() {
    const isPaid = this.state
    const {test} = this.props
    let config = {
      "publicKey": "*****",
      "productIdentity": "1234567890",
      "eventHandler": {
        onSuccess (payload) {
          console.log(payload);
        },
        onError (error) {
          // handle errors
          console.log(error);
        },
        onClose (){
          console.log('widget is closing');
          //Want to add some callback here to test()

          const {test} = this.props //The issue is here           
          console.log(test) //getting Undefined
          test(); //TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined


          //OR

          console.log(isPaid) //I get state as log
          this.setState({isPaid: !isPaid}) //TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

        }
      }
    };
    let checkout = new paygateway(config);
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ () => {checkout.show({amount: 1000})} }>Test</button>

      </div>
    )
```

Comment: You're deconstructing test from `this.props` and the function doesn't exist in props. Use `const test = this.test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're deconstructing `test` from this.props and the function doesn't exist in props. It's simply a function you've declared within the component. So, you should just assign test variable to the test function like so:

```
const test = this.test
```